# ¿Como puedo reducir este codigo? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de generar enlaces de manera automarica para un capitulo a otro (en diferentes .html) me salio este codigo pero creo que es demasiado largo como podria redurcirlo/mejorarlo

```
<html>

<body>
    <div id="caps">
    </div>
<script>
    let url = "capitulo-10.html" //window.location;
    let str = url.toString();
    let numcap = str.slice(-7, -5);
    let res = str.slice(0, -8);

    let ant = parseInt(numcap) - 1;
    let sig = parseInt(numcap) + 1;

    let caps = document.querySelector("#caps");

    if (ant < 10) {
        caps.innerHTML += "<a href='" + res + "-0" + ant + ".html'>Capitulo Anterior</a><br>";
    } else {
        caps.innerHTML += "<a href='" + res + "-" + ant + ".html'>Capitulo Anterior</a><br>";
    }

    if (sig < 10) {
        caps.innerHTML += "<a href='" + res + "-0" + sig + ".html'>Capitulo Siguiente</a><br>";
    } else {
        caps.innerHTML += "<a href='" + res + "-" + sig + ".html'>Capitulo Siguiente</a><br>";
    }
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se me ocurre lo siguiente: Usar *string templates* y el operador ternario.

además, `+'<numero entero como texto>'` es casi lo mismo que `parseInt('<numero entero como texto>')`

```
let url = "capitulo-10.html" //window.location;
let str = url.toString();
let numcap = str.slice(-7, -5);
let res = str.slice(0, -8);

let ant = +numcap - 1;
let sig = +numcap + 1;

ant = ant < 10 ? '0' + ant : ant;
sig = sig < 10 ? '0' + sig : sig;

let caps = document.querySelector("#caps");
caps.innerHTML += `<a href="${res}-${ant}.html">Capitulo Anterior</a><br>`;
caps.innerHTML += `<a href="${res}-${sig}.html">Capitulo Siguiente</a><br>`;
```